# Return characters in a string from field's data

Tags: apex, string

I have to return specific characters from a field's data. The scenario is I have a Text field which has some data (a1h5D0000055ZLfETC-547561-12) and I need to find and return last 2 characters from the data. How to achieve the same.

Comment: How do you like to show, as a formula field or want to use in apex?

Comment: I need to use this in apex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `right()` method.

```
String inputStr = 'a1h5D0000055ZLfETC-547561-12';
String resultStr = inputStr.right(2);

System.debug('inputStr  '+inputStr);
System.debug('resultStr  '+resultStr);
```

Output:

```
11:36:05:002 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|inputStr  a1h5D0000055ZLfETC-547561-12
11:36:05:002 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|resultStr  12
```

There are more [String Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use substring method of [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
String str = 'a1h5D0000055ZLfETC-547561-12';
String resultantStr = str.substring(str.length()-2);
```

It will return `12` i.e. last 2 characters from `str`.

Comment: Thanks for the info... Will try and update if I face any issue.

Comment: You will not face any issues,  it's tested